# puppet: freebsd - installing package error

Tags: freebsd, puppet

I have this module:

```
class bash {

  package { "shells/bash": 
    ensure => "installed",
  }

}
```

After the execution, I found this in the puppet dashboard:

> change from absent to present failed: Could not fetch ports INDEX: 425
>   Failed to establish connection.

I don't know why it's happening, a few weeks ago this didn't happened, but now every single time with several differents machines.

Verbose mode:

```
$ puppet agent --test --debug --verbose I see

debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFreebsd: Executing '/usr/sbin/pkg_info -aoQ'
debug: Package: shells/bash: origin => {:port_category=>"shells", :port_name=>"bash"}
debug: Package: shells/bash: source => #<URI::FTP:0x801d3fca8 URL:ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/%2Fpub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8-stable/>
debug: Fetching INDEX: #<URI::FTP:0x801d31108 URL:ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8-stable/INDEX.bz2>
err: /Stage[main]/Bash/Package[shells/bash]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not fetch ports INDEX: 425 Can't build data connection: Operation timed out.
```

I can connect with ftp.freebsd.org (telnet ftp.freebsd.org 21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you connect to http://www.freebsd.org without proxy?

Maybe you have not configured your HTTP-proxy?
Or did you override ${MASTER_SITE_INDEX} in /etc/make.conf?

This looks like the output from "make fetchindex". What happens if you go to /usr/ports and enter "make fetchindex"?

Comment: I updated my question. "make fetchindex" works without problems; also I think that a freebsd port isn't a package.

Comment: According to your output, puppet seams to fetch the INDEX via FTP not HTTP. So it looks like a firewall is interfering with active FTP. Maybe you can configure Passive mode FTP or switch to HTTP

Comment: that was it. I changed my recipe to `class bash {

  package { "shells/bash":
    ensure   => "installed",
    provider => "freebsd",
    source   => "http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8.2-release/",
  }

}
` and worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Run `puppet agent --test --debug` from the FreeBSD machine. It should give you precise information about what command it is executing that is failing, which you can then execute yourself to further debug it.